# Tracking GPUImageMovie's Progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage library to filter a video (file based input). I followed instruction from https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage. What is not clear is how to track the progress of GPUImageMovie's processing.

I understand that there was "progress" property in the past. It does not seem to exist now. I am trying to show a progress bar and such a property would have been very helpful.

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you're looking, but GPUImageMovie has had a `progress` property for a while: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageMovie.h which does just this.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I was using a much older version of GPUImage through cocoa pods. I see it now.